# Android how to create a Spinner in a center of another image (Layouts)

Tags: android, image, layout, center

I would like to create a Progress Spinner center of an image before it loads . But I have no idea how to center in to in an image . Is there any way to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

You make it like this:

- one RelativeLayout which holds:
- one ImageView match-match
- one Progress Spinner which has centerInParent attribute set to true.

Answer (score 0):

Try as below :

```
<FrameLayout>
<ImageView></ImageView>
<Spinner android:layout_gravity="center"></Spinner>
</FrameLayout>
```